# attributes for bootstrapping my website

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

what attributes do i need to add to my .css file for bootstrap to work?
I've been looking on w3schools website. got the following script ;

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

however on their tutorial it also links to a css file whereas if i add the css file they provide I lose all the formatting that I've already done.

Comment: Are you saying that when you include this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">`, it is overriding your current CSS? If so... what classes/ids specifically?

Comment: yes when i add that into my code, it takes everything set in my css file out. am i adding it in wrong? sorry not sure what you mean by what classes/ids, im a beginner sorry

Comment: What do you mean by "it takes everything set in my css file out"? Where you adding it? And how are you adding your own CSS files etc?

Comment: i have my css file setup with different fonts etc, but when i add <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">   for some reason they are lost. i currently add my css file with the following : <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loans.css"> @AdamJeffers

Comment: do i need to have both lines of code in my php file?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question in none.  You don't need to add anything to your .css file in order for Bootstrap to work.

What you need to do is add Bootstrap to the `head` section of your HTML or PHP document.  There are many articles online on how to do this, including Bootstrap's own website.  Do a little digging yourself.